# how to get specific column value after filling dataset with tableadapter

Tags: c#, .net

for example:

table1 has two columns "col1" and "col2"

```
this.table1TableAdapter.FillByParam(appDataSet.table1,param);
```

this returns 1 row

how to set col1 and col2 values to variable?
It would be great if someone post example with code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line fills a given `DataTable` from the query that is specififed as `SelectCommand` in the `TableAdapter`. So you say that it just contains a single record?

You can use `FirstOrDefault` to get that `DataRow`. Since it's a strongly typed `DataTable` you have an autogenerated `DataTable` and `DataRow` with typed properties and names that are the same as the ctypes and names in database.

So assuming you have two `Label` controls which `Text` properties you want to set from the two properties in the row:

```
appDataSet.table1Row row = appDataSet.table1.FirstOrDefault();
if(row != null)
{
    Label1.Text = row.col1;
    Label2.Text = row.col2;
}
```